# Trying to open a 32 bit image

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to open a 32 bit image on opencv and failing to do that.  Here is the code:

```
IplImage *im32 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(objectImg), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
cvSaveImage("test32.tiff", im32, NULL);
```

The output provides me a 8 bit image, which is not what I need.

Comment: You most probably want to add the OpenCV tag to your question besides **C**.

Comment: Are you sure `test32.tiff` is actually a 32-bit image?

Comment: yes i am sure it is 32 bit image;  i am not sure how i can save and view the image as 32bit.  please help

Comment: How was this image created? I assume by 32-bit you mean it's a floating point image?  You can use `tiffinfo` (part of `libtiff`) to read the headers and verify it is a 32-bit image, as read by the TIFF libraries.  Photoshop can view these files; few others seem to be capable. You could always use `convert` from ImageMagick to convert it to 8-bit for display.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Here is the code:

Comment: The image was creaed by deviding a 16bit signed image with another 16 bit signed image, the software than provides a 32 bit image, it has floating point number as well as infinity values.